# Can we cap throughput in ADF copy activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azcopy

Is there any way to cap throughput in ADF copy activity like we have in AzCopy ?

This is needed to ensure our Ingestion ( parallel Ingestion of all tables of a given source) doesn't consume all the available bandwidth

Comment: A similar question was asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62401304/throttle-bandwidth-for-a-copy-activity-in-adf, but generally if you use Self-Hosted with a VM and QoS group policy then yes.  Otherwise for Azure Integration Runtime you are modifying the max DUI and parallelism values (in settings) to indirectly control throughput.

Answer (score 0):

No we cannot. As the docs suggest, the best throughput is given.

[image]

When you run copy's in parallel, this shouldnt be a problem, as long as your source do not have any other task that is occupying the bandwidth (aside from these copy's).

If you reach throttling in the data store, reduce the concurrent workload. Maybe reducing the best throughput will be supported in future, but I doubt it as you will be overpaying for the resources you will not be using, because in the end you will still be occupying the same DIUs.

Comment: A throttling mechanism was placed on SHIR VM to control the allowed QoS

Comment: @azuresnowflake1, right i was talking about azure IR in this case. I saw the other answer to the question quoted above. You can indirectly limit throughput on SHIR of course, but you cant on Azure IR. (you did not specify initially what kind of IR you were talking about).

Comment: @azuresnowflake1, when asking questions like this, its best to be extremely detailed as possible, and give all details about the copy settings you have, or otherwise there might be misunderstanding :)